# AWS child process output bad JSON

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm currently getting this error from my AWS apigateway api using Postman:

```
{
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "child process output bad JSON: ",
    "stack": [
        "Error: child process output bad JSON: ",
        "    at _homogeneousError (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:13:12)",
        "    at postError (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:30:51)",
        "    at done (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:57:7)",
        "    at fail (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:69:7)",
        "    at /var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:105:16",
        "    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)"
    ]
```

My json payload is as follows:

```
{ "resource" : "/updatepic"
, "body" : "pleasework"}
```

My end point is: `https://xxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/updatepic`

I'm not sure if I'm formatting my JSON payload correctly. I've tried many variations but I'm getting timeouts and the bad JSON error above.

Update:
This is my event JSON parser:

```
instance FromJSON Event where
  parseJSON = withObject "Event" $ \v -> do
    bd <- v .: "body"
    rs <- v .: "resource"
    pure $ Event bd rs
```

Comment: Can you check the CloudWatch logs to see if your Lambda is actually being invoked? I'm guessing it is and you have an error somewhere in that code. If so add the code to your question and please also specify what language and runtime you are using.

Comment: @KMo my lamba function is being invoked. I'm using the haskell runtime (serverless-haskell). I think its my JSON parser and/or the post payload because if I send my POST request with no payload it says "not enough input" and my lambda function executes to completion. I added the JSON parser  for the so called "event" above.

Comment: Probably worth outputting the event to logs to check if it arrives as you expect. Also worth noting that the bad JSON bit in the error message just means an error was returned from Haskell to the js wrapper, so may have nothing to do with the json.